# How to split a pandas dataframe of different column sizes into separate dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large pandas dataframe, consisting of a different number of columns throughout the dataframe.
Here is an example: [Current dataframe example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNSS6.png)

I would like to split the dataframe into multiple dataframes, based on the number of columns it has.

Example output image here:[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86WN3.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear, you should explain yourself better. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58359395/edit) your post, add a sample input and output.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.Updated with example input dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dataframe of say 10 columns and you want to put the records with 3 `NaN` values in another result dataframe as those with 1 `NaN`, you can do this as follows:

```
# evaluate the number of NaNs per row
num_counts=df.isna().sum('columns')
# group by this number and add the grouped
# dataframe to a dictionary
results= dict()
num_counts=df.isna().sum('columns')
for key, sub_df in df.groupby(num_counts):
    results[key]= sub_df
```

After executing this code, results contains subsets of `df` where each subset contains the same number of `NaN`s (so the same number of non-`NaN`s).

If you want to write your results to a excel file, you just need to execute the following code:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('sorted_output.xlsx') as writer:
    for key, sub_df in results.items():
        # if you want to avoid the detour of using dicitonaries
        # just replace the previous line by
        # for key, sub_df in df.groupby(num_counts):
        sub_df.to_excel(
            writer,
            sheet_name=f'missing {key}',
            na_rep='',
            inf_rep='inf',
            float_format=None,
            index=True,
            index_label=True,
            header=True)
```

Example:

```
# create an example dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], b=list('abbcac')))
df.loc[[2, 4, 5], 'c']= list('xyz')
df.loc[[2, 3, 4], 'd']= list('vxw')
df.loc[[1, 2], 'e']= list('qw')
```

It looks like this:

```
Out[58]: 
   a  b    c    d    e
0  1  a  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  2  b  NaN  NaN    q
2  3  b    x    v    w
3  4  c  NaN    x  NaN
4  5  a    y    w  NaN
5  6  c    z  NaN  NaN
```

If you execute the code above on this dataframe, you get a dictionary with the following content:

```
0:    a  b  c  d  e
   2  3  b  x  v  w

1:    a  b  c  d    e
   4  5  a  y  w  NaN

2:    a  b    c    d    e
   1  2  b  NaN  NaN    q
   3  4  c  NaN    x  NaN
   5  6  c    z  NaN  NaN

3:    a  b    c    d    e
   0  1  a  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

The keys of the dictionary are the number of `NaN`s in the row and the values are the dataframes which contain only rows with that number of `NaN`s in them.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting you right, what you want to do is to split existing 1 dataframe with `n` columns into `ceil(n/5)` dataframes, each with 5 columns, and the last one with the reminder of `n/5`.

If that's the case this will do the trick:

```py
import pandas as pd
import math

max_cols=5

dt={"a": [1,2,3], "b": [6,5,3], "c": [8,4,2], "d": [8,4,0], "e": [1,9,5], "f": [9,7,9]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=dt)

dfs=[df[df.columns[max_cols*i:max_cols*i+max_cols]] for i in range(math.ceil(len(df.columns)/max_cols))]

for el in dfs:
    print(el)
```

And output:

```py
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  6  8  8  1                                            
1  2  5  4  4  9                                            
2  3  3  2  0  5                                               
   f                                                        
0  9                                                        
1  7                                                        
2  9                                                        

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you - I think my question is a little confusing. I have a huge dataframe with different columns lengths ranging from 4-8. I would like to split this dataframe into a smaller dataframes based on the number of columns. So if there are 4 columns then this should be picked up as one df. If there are 7 this would be split as another.

Comment: Hm, could you be more specific on the part of input - it's one dataframe with different length of columns- define what do you mean by "column length" - number of characters, number of elements stored in each row (in e.g. list)